# Не выполняется запрос к MySql java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysqlconnector

```
public void Registration(String name, String secondName, int grade, String gradeLatter, int schoolNumber) throws SQLException{
    Connection connection = new Connection();
    String login = secondName + "_" + name.charAt(0) + grade + "_" + schoolNumber;
    PreparedStatement regPS = connection.childCon().prepareStatement
            ("INSERT INTO children.childreninfo (name, secondName, login, schoolNumber, grade, gradeLatter) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    regPS.setString(1,name);
    regPS.setString(2,secondName);
    regPS.setString(3,login);
    regPS.setInt(4,schoolNumber);
    regPS.setInt(5,grade);
    regPS.setString(6,gradeLatter);
    regPS.executeQuery();
    regPS.close();
    connection.childCon().close();
}
```

Подключение:

```
public class Connection {
private String childrenURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/children?useSSL=false";
private String childrenUser = "root";
private String childrenPass = "root";


public java.sql.Connection childCon() throws SQLException {
    Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
    DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
    java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(childrenURL, childrenUser, childrenPass);
    return connection;
}
```

}

Указывает на `executeQuery`, но почему не понимаю. Проект JavaFX c установленным mysql-connector-5.1.38.

Comment: А где собсно подключение? Ну или хотя бы его параметры?

Comment: обновил, класс подключени есть:)

Answer (score 0):

Надо было вместо `executeQuery()` использовать `executeUpdate()`